# Yarn Distributed cache, no mapper/reducer

Tags: java, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, distributed-cache

I am unable to access files in distributed cache in Hadoop 2.6. Below is a code snippet. I am attempting to place a file `pattern.properties`, which is in `args[0]` in the distributed cache of Yarn

```
Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf1);
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[0]), conf1);
```

Also, I am trying to access the file in cache using the below:

```
Context context =null;
URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();  //Error at this line
System.out.println(cacheFiles);
```

But I am getting the below error at the line mentioned above:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am not using Mapper class. It's just a spark stream code to access a file in cluster. I want the file to be distributed in the cluster. But I can't take it from HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I understood your question correctly.

We had some local files which we need to access in Spark streaming jobs.

We used this option:-

> time spark-submit --files
>   /user/dirLoc/log4j.properties#log4j.properties 'rest other options'

Another way we tried was :- SparkContext.addFile()

Comment: Thanks! This helped. We have done this and the job is working.